# Android Passkey issue

Tags: android

Exception message：

GetCredentialException: activity is cancelled by the user.
androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is cancelled by the user.

Android API：android 13

Description：
When attempting to validate a passkey without the device having a screen lock set, and encountering issues where the guided process does not complete successfully after calling the passkey API。

The passkey API can be successfully configured to complete the verification process.